# Verificar se a Coluna possui um valor em Branco ou Vazio

Tags: jquery

Bom dia.
Estou tentando verificar se a coluna de uma tabela Pai-Filho ficou em branco.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
// VERIFICA SE ALGUM COLUNA FICOU EM BRANCO
var elVlr = $('#itensInventario tbody > tr > td input.linhaItemInventario');
$.each(elVlr, function(i, el) {
    if ($("#tb_NEX").val() == null || $("#tb_NEX").val() == "") {
    Status = "erro";
    }
});
```

Comment: Está dando algum erro? Pelo que vi, seu código está ok. Explique melhor a situação por favor.

Comment: se tiver um modelo minimo de como esta a estrutura da sua tabela, ajuda mais, pois acredito que você está olhando sempre no mesmo item

Answer (score 0):

Como você está usando o `$.each` pra percorrer seu array de inputs, você precisa verificar se o elemento atual está preenchido ou não `$(el).val()` e não utilizar um novo seletor atraves do id `$("#tn_NEX").val()`.

Basicamente o que você precisa é trocar `$("#tn_NEX").val()` por `$(el).val()` e deve alcançar o que você deseja.